# Grails and css / javascript libraries

Tags: javascript, css, grails

I'm attempting to use [leaflet.js](http://leafletjs.com/) within a grails application. My folder structure looks like this:

```
grails-app
    assets
        images
            marker-icon.png
            ...
    javascripts
        application.js
        leaflet.js
        main.js
    stylsheets
        application.css
        leaflet.css
```

and then in main.gsp:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title><g:layoutTitle default="Grails"/></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <asset:stylesheet src="application.css"/>
    <asset:javascript src="application.js"/>

    <g:layoutHead/>
```

On load, I'm getting the following errors:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/assets/images/marker-icon.png 404 (Not Found) index:1 
GET http://localhost:8080/assets/images/marker-shadow.png 404 (Not Found)
```

even though those files are clearly located in the 'assets' folder and labled properly.

**What is the best way to handle extra javascript / css files in grails?**

Answer (score 0):

Do you add leaflet.js to applications .js as //=require leaflet ?Where do you use images?

Comment: the images are called by the leaflet css that I have added.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1st option)
Try updating the references in leaflet.css to remove "images/"

Ex: 
From background-image: url(images/layers.png); 
to background-image: url(layers.png);

2nd option)
Create images folder under grails-app/assets/images

Let me know if it works.